# R pass vector into SQL statement for column choice

Tags: r, r-dbi, rsqlite, rjdbc, rsql

Good afternoon all,

I could not find an answer to this particular question.

I have a list of users and am using R DBI and RJDBC package to extract some data from online server.

I have a list of user id numbers and a vector of column names likeso

```
users <- c("1432","1822","1888")
column_vec <- c("Year","Payment","Status")
```

Currently my function looks like this

```
extraction <- function(user_list) {
  users <- as.character(user_list)
  
  first <- glue_sql("SELECT * FROM table WHERE UTR_NO IN ({ID*})",
                                  ID = users,
                                  .con = conn)
  
  second <- dbSendQuery(conn, first )
  third <-dbFetch(second )
  return(third )
  }
```

It works fine however there are two changes that I would like to make to this function:

1. I would like to only pick up columns specified in the vector instead of all columns. I have tried many approaches (parametrization with '?' for example) but nothing seems to work.
2. I would also like to have a dynamic variable for table (this one worked for some of my approaches)

Any help would be much appreciated

Kind regards

Przemek

below is my freshest attempt that still gives me error

```
extraction <- function(user_list) {
  users <- as.character(user_list)

  first <- glue_sql("SELECT {columns} FROM table WHERE UTR_NO IN ({ID*})",
                                  columns = column_vec,
                                   ID = users,
                                  .con = conn)

  second <- dbSendQuery(conn, first )
  third <-dbFetch(second )
  return(third )
  }
```

The output from this query looks like this. It is column name just copied across cells
1       2        3
Year  Payment  Status
Year  Payment  Status
Year  Payment  Status
Year  Payment  Status
Year  Payment  Status
Year  Payment  Status

Comment: What is the error that is given?

Comment: And shouldn't `"SELECT {columns}` be `"SELECT {columns*}`

Comment: `glue_sql("SELECT {columns*} FROM table WHERE UTR_NO IN ({ID*})", columns = column_vec, ID = users, .con = conn)` works for me

Comment: BTW, your function doesn't have an argument for `column_vec`, so while it might work if you have already define it in the calling or global environment, this is a break in functional programming. I suggest you should define the args as `function(user_list, column_vec)` and call it appropriately. BTW #2: instead of the `dbSendQuery`+`dbFetch` combo, it's the same results but ***safer*** to do a single `dbGetQuery(conn, first)`.